# How to add shortcut for `open in terminal` option in fedora?

Tags: linux, command-line, fedora

Isn't there any shortcut for `open in terminal` option. Inside folder you should right click and then choose `open in terminal`. Is it possible to make it easier and add shortcut for this?

Answer (score 1):

You need gnome terminal extension for nautilus to be able to use `open in terminal` option.
Install gnome-terminal-nautilus:

```
sudo dnf install gnome-terminal-nautilus
```

more infomation:
https://fedora.pkgs.org/33/fedora-x86_64/gnome-terminal-nautilus-3.38.0-1.fc33.x86_64.rpm.html

Comment: What should I do then? There is no guide in the site.

Comment: restart nautilus with ```nautilus --quit``` and you should have an "open in terminal" option.